# using directories from java jar application

Tags: java, jar

I have java app, where I copy directories (with subdir and files) to SDCard. I wanted to save these dirs with project. In eclipse everything works fine. But, when I export project to runnable jar, app is not able to find or copy these dirs. No error is showed.

```
File folder2 = new File(getClass().getResource("/urgent/").getFile());
File folder4 = new File(getClass().getResource("/service/").getFile());
```

The path, I get from jar app, when I want to copy dir is:

```
jar:file:\C:\path\to\jar\file\myapp.jar!\urgent
```

project hierarchy:

```
-project
 --src
 --build
 --urgent
  ---subdir
 --service
  ---subdir
```

Is it possible to work with your own directories in jar and how?

Comment: If you want to use directories, then you shouldn't be using `getResource()`... `getResource()` is for getting things from the class path, which may not be directories. If you want to use directories, you should be using `File` or `Path`, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to work on resources on you classpath, a random folder on your harddrive is not in it, so you cannot find it.

What you need to do is:
1. Work with parameters from the commandline (see how to use args[] in your main method)
2. use those arguments to parametrize your custom copy mehod

or:

Try using the copyDirectory(File srcDir, File destDir) method from the Apache Commons IO library instead. To use this reearch how to include libraries in your project, preferably by using maven.